# facebook using jquerymobile frame work

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, jquery-mobile

I am trying to implement the basic features of facebook like updating the facebook profile, and also facebook login using jquerymobile frame work. Using this link http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

It works fine with HTML 5 format. But when I integrate with the JqueryMobile, I am getting an error which says Uncaught exception: cant call method appendChild.

I will paste the code here: please have a look and let me know whats the problem.

```
<body> 
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

                FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});



                /* All the events registered */

                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {

                    // do something with response

                    login();

                });

                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {

                    // do something with response

                    logout();

                });



                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

                    if (response.session) {

                        // logged in and connected user, someone you know

                        login();

                    }

                });

            };

            (function() {

                var e = document.createElement('script');

                e.type = 'text/javascript';

                e.src = document.location.protocol +

                    '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';

                e.async = true;

                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e); //i am getting error in the is line

            });



            function login(){

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                    document.getElementById('login').style.display = "block";

                    document.getElementById('login').innerHTML = response.name + " succsessfully logged in!";

                });

            }

            function logout(){

                document.getElementById('login').style.display = "none";

            }



            //stream publish method

            function streamPublish(name, description, hrefTitle, hrefLink, userPrompt){

                FB.ui(

                {

                    method: 'stream.publish',

                    message: '',

                    attachment: {

                        name: name,

                        caption: '',

                        description: (description),

                        href: hrefLink

                    },

                    action_links: [

                        { text: hrefTitle, href: hrefLink }

                    ],

                    user_prompt_message: userPrompt

                },

                function(response) {



                });



            }

            function showStream(){

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                    //console.log(response.id);

                    streamPublish(response.name, 'Something ', 'hrefTitle', 'http://www.ffff.com', "Share www.ffffff.com");

                });

            }



            function share(){

                var share = {

                    method: 'stream.share',

                    u: 'http://www.fffffff.com'

                };



                FB.ui(share, function(response) { console.log(response); });

            }



            function graphStreamPublish(){

                var body = 'hsdfkjasdkjfadkjf;adlfj';

                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {

                    if (!response || response.error) {

                        alert('Error occured');

                    } else {

                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);

                    }

                });

            }



            function fqlQuery(){

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                     var query = FB.Data.query('select name, hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid={0}', response.id);

                     query.wait(function(rows) {



                       document.getElementById('name').innerHTML =

                         'Your name: ' + rows[0].name + "<br />" +

                         '<img src="' + rows[0].pic_square + '" alt="" />' + "<br />";

                     });

                });

            }



            function setStatus(){

                status1 = document.getElementById('status').value;

                FB.api(

                  {

                    method: 'status.set',

                    status: status1

                  },

                  function(response) {

                    if (response == 0){

                        alert('Your facebook status not updated. Give Status Update Permission.');

                    }

                    else{

                        alert('Your facebook status updated');

                    }

                  }

                );

            }
            </script>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Foofys-Facebook Page</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>you are using foofys facebook app</p>
         <div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream"> </fb:login-button>



        <p>

            <a href="#" onclick="showStream(); return false;">Publish Wall Post</a> |

           <!-- <a href="#" onclick="share(); return false;">Share With Your Friends</a> | -->

            <a href="#" onclick="graphStreamPublish(); return false;">Publish Stream</a> |

           <!-- <a href="#" onclick="fqlQuery(); return false;">FQL Query Example</a> -->

        </p>



        <textarea id="status" cols="50" rows="5">Write your status here'</textarea>

        <br />

      <!--  <a href="#" onclick="setStatus(); return false;">Status Set Using Legacy Api Call</a> -->



        <br /><br /><br />

        <div id="login" style ="display:none"></div>

        <div id="name"></div>       
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
```

i am not able to understand whats happening in the code, BTW I have just pointed where exactly I am getting the error.

Comment: Can you verify that `document.getElementById('fb-root')` is actually getting an element. Don't know why it wouldn't though...

Comment: Nope its not getting since I am not able to get the facebook login button

Comment: Try to move `<div id="fb-root"></div>` up, and use it as first child of your body tag.

Comment: other than moving the div after the <body> tag I also had to add ()
in the line after the "//i am getting error in the is line" comment. 
So basically I changed the line "});" into "}());".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick with JQM and FB api is to use the graph API. That is DO NOT use the simple javascript FB wrappers since they are unstable when exposed to JQM's page handling - instead just use the new graph / rest API, check for and avoid multiple inits of the FB core and your'e set. For instance

```
function updateUserInfo(uid, accessToken) {

    var uri = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + uid;
    console.log("About to call FP.api with URI " + uri);    

    $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/" + uid,
                dataType: "json",
                success: 
                    (function (response) {
                        console.log("About to call check profile ...");
                        $("#p_name").val(response.name);
                        $("#email").val(response.email);
                        $("#fb_id").val(response.id);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/check_profile",
                            cache: false,
                            data: {fb_id: response.id},
                            success: onCheckSuccess,
                            error: onError
                        });
                        console.log("FB id: " + response.id);                     
                    }),
                error: onError
         });
```